# Entity framework foreignkey

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am getting the following error, while clearing the child records and adding them back to the parent.

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

Comment: What code is being used that is generating this error? Can you include the SQL or other related code?

Comment: please include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, including the code that is causing this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete data if which is referenced to another table as foreign key, but you done through

Remove value from referenced table after then you can able to perform delete operation only

try this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/entity-framework-error-the-relationship-could-not-be-chang/